# Does AtTask event subscription work?

Tags: api, events, attask

Has anyone had success with AtTask event subscriptions through the API?

I have successfully registered a subscription, seen here:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "52a4c50100008ac5bb38ed45a6191a3f",
      "objCode": "EVTSUB",
      "entryDate": "2013-12-08T14:14:09:756-0500",
      "fields": "[\"*\"]",
      "filters": "{\"name_Mod\":\"cinotcontains\",\"name\":\"Test\"}",
      "lastUpdateDate": "2013-12-08T14:14:09:756-0500",
      "lastUpdatedByID": "5266f6be002bbd546e91a21028180509",
      "notificationURL": "http://ec2-54-196-33-85.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "subscriptionObjCode": "TASK",
      "type": "ADD"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I create a task called "deleteme" nothing is sent to the notificationUrl, which I'm quite positive is exposed to the internet.

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 1):

Notifications of registered event subscriptions are currently turned off due to unexpected volume of outward notifications that is beyond what AtTask servers can handle since AtTask launched this feature few weeks ago.

AtTask is actively addressing this scalability issue.  Although this is a temporary situation, at the moment AtTask does not yet have an ETA on when this issue will be resolved.

We sincerely apologies for any inconvenience and frustration.  Thank you for your patience in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

This has been turned on again in the API, currently in Preview Sandbox:
https://support.workfront.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000135574-Event-Subscription-API