# AtTask create/update a custom field through API on project creation created through AtTask's web app

Tags: api, events, attask

I'm looking to use AtTask's API to update or create a custom field (ie. assign a custom ID apart from AtTask's auto-generated id) whenever a project is created through the web app. But I have not found anything about handling events in the API documentation.

I'm able to retrieve/edit project fields when issuing a request by ID or some other search parameter.
But I'm having trouble finding ways to edit project fields on some event like 'project created'.

One way I can think of is to have my script periodically search for new projects based on project metadata and edit projects that way, but there must be a better solution I probably missed.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
It seems 'AtTask event subscriptions' was what I was looking for. At the time of the post below (12/2013), due to scalability issues, AtTask has turned this feature turned off with no ETA on resolving the issue. See here: [Does AtTask event subscription work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457874/does-attask-event-subscription-work)

Any updates would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the AtTask API does not currently support events.  The easiest thing to do is to just poll the system for updates using the search.  You could also monitor an email address for emails that are sent upon project creation.  The email will contain the project/task/issue ID that you can use to update events.